# eonasdan Bootstrap datetimepicker invalid date conversion

Tags: datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have a 
[DateTimePicker Bootstrap](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) that has a fixed format.

```
$('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY'
});
```

Everything works fine but when I try to paste a date on it with a different format, it converts it to a wrong date.

The date I pasted is `01/02/2016` and the result I get from the datetimepicker is `Tue, 01 Jan 0002` when I hit tab.

It converts it to the date format I set but the date is wrong. I tried converting it onchange but I know there should be a cleaner and better way to handle this.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datetimepicker has [`extraFormats`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#extraformats) option that lets you specify multiple formats. In your case, you can use the following code as example:

```js
$('.datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'ddd, DD MMM YYYY',
    extraFormats: ['ddd, DD MMM YYYY', 'DD/MM/YYYY']
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group date datetimepicker1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You sir are awesome! I saw this on the documentation but I focused on datetime parsing. Should have read more. Thank you sir!